# Trying to Create a Profile Image system

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to create a profile image upload system on my page, but I'm having a challenge, the pictures echo four times, the default picture displays four times on the page and when I upload a picture it does the same. I need help on how to resolve this, I need only one image displaying on the page.

```
<?php
require("./includes/databaseHandler.php");
$id = $usersData['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
    while(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $sqlImg = "SELECT * FROM profileimg WHERE userid = '$id'";
        $resultImg = mysqli_query($con, $sqlImg);
        while($rowImg = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultImg)){
            echo "<div class='user-container'>";
                if($rowImg['status'] == 0){
                    echo "<img src = 'uploads/profile".$id.".jpg' >";
                }else{
                    echo "<img src = 'uploads/profiledefault.jpg'>";
                }
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: you are trying to create ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not fetching the result of the first query into a usable variable, so you dont have the `$id` set for each user returned by the first query

> NOTE: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
>   Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
>   You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

So I have also made use of prepared parameterised statements in my answer.

```
<?php
require("./includes/databaseHandler.php");

// I assume this was a fudge to get it working
//$id = $usersData['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){

    // prepare query here ONCE and use it may times with amended parameters    
    $sqlImg = "SELECT * FROM profileimg WHERE userid = ?";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($sqlImg);

    while($user = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    //    ^^^^^
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $user['id']);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();

        while($rowImg = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<div class='user-container'>";
                if($rowImg['status'] == 0){
                    echo "<img src = 'uploads/profile" .$user['id']. ".jpg' >";
                }else{
                    echo "<img src = 'uploads/profiledefault.jpg'>";
                }
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't think you should be overwriting the `$result` inside of the loop.